# How can I cap my result to 1 with importXML

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using importXML I am searching for the class 'current' which contains 'current-price'.
Using this code it returns the same result 3 times as the 'current' class exists 3 times on the website.

```
=importxml("https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/tv-and-home-entertainment/televisions/televisions/lg-55sm8200pla-55-smart-4k-ultra-hd-hdr-led-tv-with-google-assistant-10191769-pdt.html", "//div//strong[contains(@class, 'current')]")
```

[image]

Is there a simple way to cap my search to 1 result so that it doesn't overlap data on the row below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, you can use `INDEX` like:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/tv-and-home-entertainment/televisions/televisions/lg-55sm8200pla-55-smart-4k-ultra-hd-hdr-led-tv-with-google-assistant-10191769-pdt.html", 
 "//div//strong[contains(@class, 'current')]"), 1, 1)
```